# Receive, Parse and Respond to Email

Tags: email, parse-server

(This is a newbie question, requesting answers that will point me in the right general direction).

What would be the best way to receive emails, parse their content and send different email replies based upon certain words appearing in the content?

I have a server running CentOS Linux and WHM/CPanel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I need to parse incoming emails?](http://serverfault.com/questions/140120/what-do-i-need-to-parse-incoming-emails)

Comment: Thank you, Ignacio, for drawing my attention to that question, which is somewhat related, but only covers the receiving and parsing aspects.

I am asking if there might be some sort of solution or existing product that enables the entire sequence, possibly already part of WHM/CPanel or easily integrated.

I have amended my questions tags to more clearly specify WHM and CPanel.

Comment: Perhaps you want an "autoresponder" then.

Comment: Well, an autoresponder might be the correct solution if one exists that is sophisticated enough to send different replies depending on certain words appearing in the received content.  I am pretty sure that such software must exist but, at the moment, I don't know how to find it, hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

*procmail*

This is exactly what procmail is designed to do.

[procmail Homepage](http://www.procmail.org/)

You still need to write procmail *recipes* to act on the e-mail, but it's powerful and flexible.

Comment: Thanks EightBitTony, I will start researching procmail.  According to Wikipedia, the project is no longer maintained, so I am still interested in hearing about any other possible approaches, but very grateful for this first pointer.